# Is google app engine right for me (hosting a few rapidly updating text files created w/ python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a python script that creates a few text files, which are then uploaded to my current web host. This is done every 5 minutes. The text files are used in a software program which fetches the latest version every 5 min. Right now I have it running on my web host, but I'd like to move to GAE to improve reliability. (Also because my current web host does not allow for just plain file hosting, per their TOS.)

Is google app engine right for me? I have some experience with python, but none related to web technologies. I went through the basic hello world tutorial and it seems pretty straightforward for a website, but I don't know how I would implement my project. I also worry about any caching which could cause the latest files not to propagate fast enough across google's servers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

Appengine is great in terms of reliability, server speed, features, etc.  However, it has two main drawbacks: You are in a sandboxed environment (no filesystem access, must use datastore), and you are paying by instance hour.  Normally, if you're just hosting a small server accessed once in a while, you can get free hosting; if you are running a cron job all day every day, you must use at least one instance at all times, thus costing you money.

Your concerns about speed and propagation on google's servers is moot; they have a global time server pulsating through their datacenters ensuring your operations are atomic; if you request data with consistency=STRONG, so long as your get begins after the put, you will see the updated data.

Answer (score 0):

If your text files are always going to be under one meg, and you are not planning to scale to a large number of users, it would very easy to set up a system to post your text files into an entity as a TextProperty. If you are a complete newbie to GAE it is probably < 1 hours to get this running. I do this a lot to speed testing of my HTML work (beats deploying your static files by a mile). Here is some very simple code extracts as an example. (Apologies if I screwed it up when modifying it to simplify/anonimize.) HTH -stevep

```
#client side python...

import time
import urllib
import httplib


def processUpdate(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'rb')
    parts = filename.split('/')
    name = parts[len(parts)-1]
    print name
    html = f.read()
    f.close()
    htmlToLoad = urllib.quote(html)
    params = urllib.urlencode({'key':'your_arbitrary_password_here(or use admin account)',
                                'name':name,
                                'htmlToLoad':htmlToLoad,
                                })
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
    #conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('your_localhost_here')
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('your_app_id_here')
    conn.request('POST', '/your_on-line_handler_url_stub_here', params, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    print '%s, %s, %s' % (filename, response.status, response.reason)


def main():
    startTime = time.time()
    print '----------Start Process----------\n'
    processUpdate('your_full_file01_path_here')
    processUpdate('your_full_file02_path_here')
    processUpdate('your_full_file03_path_here')
    print '\n----------End Process----------', time.time() - startTime

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


# GAE Kind
class Html_Source(db.Model):
    html = db.TextProperty(required=True, indexed=False)
    dateM = db.DateTimeProperty(required=True, indexed=False, auto_now=True)
    v = db.IntegerProperty(required=False, indexed=False, default=1)


#GAE handler classes

EVENTUAL = db.create_config(read_policy=db.EVENTUAL_CONSISTENCY)


class load_test(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.response.clear()
        if (self.request.get('key') != 'your_arbitrary_password_here(or use admin account)'):
            logging.info("----------------------------------bad key")
            return
        name = self.request.get('name')
        rec = Html_Source(
                    key_name = name,
                    html = urllib.unquote(self.request.get('htmlToLoad')),
                    )
        rec.put()
        self.response.out.write('OK=' + name)


class get_test(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        urlList = self.request.url.split('/')
        name = urlList[len(urlList) - 1]
        extension = name.split('.')
        type = '' if len(extension) < 2 else extension[1]
        typeM = None
        if type == 'js': typeM = 'application/javascript'
        if type == 'css': typeM = 'text/css'
        if type == 'html': typeM = 'text/html'
        self.response.out.clear()
        if typeM: self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = typeM
        logging.info('%s-----name, %s-----typeM' % (name, typeM))
        htmlRec = Html_Source.get_by_key_name(name, config=EVENTUAL)
        if htmlRec is None:
            self.response.out.write('<p>invalid:%s</p>' % (name))
            return
        self.response.out.write(htmlRec.html)
```

Comment: Could you explain ""I do this a lot to speed testing of my HTML work (beats deploying your static files by a mile).""  Curious about your usage, not code.

Comment: Sure. Typically html, css, js files would be set up as static files to be delivered by GAE's content delivery system. If you are busy modifying these files, and iteratively testing on GAE's servers rather than localhost, you need to deploy your app to get the static files updated. This can be quite a long wait depending on how GAE is running. Not seconds, but often minutes or (unfortunately not too uncommonly) not at all when GAE's deployment process goes bad. By uploading and reading from the DB, worst case I've ever had is a bit more than 5 seconds for a full set of uploads. HTH. -stevep